# "Too many open files" while dumping data to elasticsearch

Tags: java, macos, jvm, elasticsearch, osx-mavericks

I'm performing a dump to elasticsearch using [Elasticsearch-Exporter](https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-Exporter) on OSX Mavericks:

`node /usr/bin/node_modules/elasticsearch-exporter/exporter.js -j ${esIndexName} -f esbackup`

I have an application that runs two nodes, which along with the application node adds up to a total of three nodes. The node created by the `elasticsearch` command is the master node. When I run the export command against my index, I get this after a few seconds of successful loading:

```
2014-05-07T14:31:38.325-0700 [elasticsearch[Rancor][[es][1]: Lucene Merge Thread #0]] [WARN] merge.scheduler [][] - [Rancor] [es][1] failed to merge
 815 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/data/core/elasticsearch_me/nodes/0/indices/es/1/index/_f_es090_0.tip (Too many open files)
```

I've tried the following:

`launchctl limit 10000`

`sudo launchctl limit 40000 65000`

`elasticsearch soft nofile 32000`

`elasticsearch hard nofile 32000`

adding `-XX:-MaxFDLimit` to my application's jvm arguments

None of which solve my problem. Occasionally the load will finish with no errors, but most of the time I run into the error. Does anyone have any ideas/hints on what my issue might be?

Edit:

`$ launchctl limit
    cpu         unlimited      unlimited

    filesize    unlimited      unlimited

    data        unlimited      unlimited

    stack       8388608        67104768

    core        0              unlimited

    rss         unlimited      unlimited

    memlock     unlimited      unlimited

    maxproc     709            1064

    maxfiles    10000          10240`

`$ sudo launchctl limit
Password:
    cpu         unlimited      unlimited

    filesize    unlimited      unlimited

    data        unlimited      unlimited

    stack       8388608        67104768

    core        0              unlimited

    rss         unlimited      unlimited

    memlock     unlimited      unlimited

    maxproc     709            1064

    maxfiles    40000          65000`

Comment: can you run launchctl limit and post the output as part of your question?

Comment: @jpsf Done. I put both the user and system limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - if you are running multiple elasticsearch nodes plus node.js apps on a single Mac I'd definitely make certain that your number of open files is bumped to the limits that ES recommends:

```
file descriptor

Make sure to increase the number of open files descriptors on the machine (or for the user running elasticsearch). Setting it to 32k or even 64k is recommended.

In order to test how many open files the process can open, start it with -Des.max-open-files set to true. This will print the number of open files the process can open on startup.

Alternatively, you can retrieve the max_file_descriptors for each node using the Nodes Info API, with:

curl localhost:9200/_nodes/process?pretty
```

You need to make certain this is done for the user running ES, not just root (unless of course you are running it as root).

To do this I'd follow these directions: (http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/quot-Too-many-open-files-quot-error-on-Mac-OSX-td4034733.html). Assuming you want 32k and 64k as the limits:

```
In /etc/launchd.conf put:

limit maxfiles 32000 64000


Make sure in your ~/.bashrc file you are not setting the ulimit with something like "ulimit -n 1024".  

Open a new terminal, and run:

launchctl limit maxfiles
ulimit -a
```

Don't forget to restart after you make these changes. Then when you start elasticsearch pass in this command line parameter:

```
elasticsearch -XX:-MaxFDLimit
```

After the above steps on my Mac I'm getting the following response from Elasticsearch:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_nodes/process?pretty

{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" : {
      "name" : "Marrina Smallwood",
      "transport_address" : "inet[XX.XX.XX.XX:9300]",
      "host" : "MacBook-Pro-Retina.local",
      "ip" : "XX.XX.XX.XX",
      "version" : "1.1.1",
      "build" : "f1585f0",
      "http_address" : "inet[/XX.XX.XX.XX:9200]",
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "id" : 538,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 32768,
        "mlockall" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Opening up `localhost:9200/_nodes/process?pretty` shows my `max_file_descriptors` to be 1000, which is low. However, the steps you listed don't seem to change that value.

Comment: I'd like you to do one more thing - add this command to the end of your call to start elasticsearch: -XX:-MaxFDLimit - I will document in edit to answer but doing that in addition to other steps has my elasticsearch reporting 32768 available descriptors on Mac OS X Mavericks